# Links in jquery dataTable not working properly

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, datatables

I am using jquery dataTables plugin.I have links in certain columns.I have entries in the tables for 4 pages.On clicking any link in the first page,the text of the link is displayed on alert.On clicking the links in second page or later,it is redirecting to href page. I didnt understand why this is happening.

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" 
src="../js/jquery_dataTable/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = 
        $('#lstCategories').DataTable({
           "bPaginate": true,
           "bSort" : false
        });
    $("a.update").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        el=$(this); 
        alert(el.text());
   return false;
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<td><a class="update" href="module/global/communication/monitored_messaging/process.php?action=notification&pub=0">UnPublish</a></td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [delegate](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) event to handle anchors added later in DOM:

```
$('#lstCategories').on('click', 'a.update', function(e){...});
```

Comment: I have used .delegate function,it was also working fine for me.Thanks bro